# gnuplot: splot pm3d artifacts when adding offset

Tags: gnuplot

Plotting a sphere `with pm3d` works fine.
However, when I want to give an offset I get some artifact which I don't unterstand.
Any ideas why I get a "black hole" into my sphere when shifting the coordinates by adding some numbers?
Created with gnuplot 5.2.8

**Code:**

```
### plotting artifact with splot and pm3d
reset session

set view equal xyz
set view 45,45, 2
unset tics
unset colorbox
unset key
set margins 0,0,0,0
unset border
set style fill solid 1.0 noborder
set pm3d depthorder noborder
set pm3d lighting specular 0.5

# Create a sphere prototype dataset
set parametric
set isosamples 25
set samples 25
set urange [-pi/2:pi/2]
set vrange [0:2*pi]
Radius = 1
set table $Sphere
    splot Radius*cos(u)*cos(v), Radius*cos(u)*sin(v), Radius*sin(u)
unset table
unset parametric

set palette defined (0 "#ff0000", 1 "#ff0000")
set view 153, 90

splot $Sphere u 1:2:3 w pm3d 
pause -1 "Press OK to see the next plot"
splot $Sphere u ($1+1.0):($2+2.0):($3+3.0) w pm3d 
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

With offset:

[image]

Comment: Sorry, you are correct. In that case I do not know what the reason is. I will remove my answer and think some more.

Comment: My suspicion is that there might be something with small numbers and rounding. `$Sphere` contains some extremely small numbers close to zero, like  `+1e-17` or `-1e-32`. Maybe because of this, the last facettes will not be plotted if you add a (relatively) large number, which results in this "black hole". But I still cannot explain it, and don't know how to workaround it.

Comment: It seems to be a glitch in the specular component of the lighting model.  I will have to investigate further.

Comment: Workaround:  trim the limit of the parametric parameter u when generating the sphere. This prevents the quadrangles that reach the poles from becoming totally degenerate: `epsilon=0.0001; set urange [epsilon - pi/2 : pi/2 - epsilon]`

Comment: Thank you, Ethan, this helps. No "black hole" anymore. Do you want to put this as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the lighting model code.  It calculates the surface normal for each quadrangle facet of the pm3d surface using the cross product (v1-v0)x(v2-v0).  In this case the quadrangles that touch the "poles" of the sphere become degenerate because two of the four vertices lie exactly on the pole, leaving only a triangle. Depending on which of the two vertices coincide, the normal becomes undefined and the lighting calculation bails out, returning 0 = black.  So that's a fixable bug, since a different choice of vertices would still allow calculating the normal.

**Workaround**:  Limit the range of the parametric variable 'u' so that the quadrangles do not quite reach the poles:

```
 epsilon=0.0001
 set urange [epsilon - pi/2 : pi/2 - epsilon]
```

For what it's worth, another workaround is `set pm3d interpolation 3,3`.  I'm not sure why that works, but it might be useful if the same problem crops up when plotting a data set that isn't generated on the spot.